# Convert textarea text into valid html

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

So there are a few paragraphs separated by line feeds "\r\n" in a textarea,  say

```
Paragraph1 "\r\n"
Paragraph2 "\r\n"
Paragraph3 "\r\n"
```

what i want to achieve is to process each paragraph into

tag. How do you do that? (Need a server side solution) 
so it looks like

```
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>
```

On top of the complexity, if you have a blockquote there

```
Paragraph1 "\r\n"
<blockquote> "\r\n"
test
</blockquote> "\r\n"
Paragraph2 "\r\n"
Paragraph3 "\r\n"
```

should come out to look like

```
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>
<blockquote>
<p>test</p>
</blockquote>
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>
```

Thanks a lot

ps: I see stackoverflow does a good job at that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a bit overkill for what you want to do, but Stackoverflow uses [**Markdown**](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). There is at least one ASP.NET converter available: [**Markdown.NET**](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx)

Comment: @Pekka. Thanks. Looks like a lot to read through in MarkDown.NET, but at least it's a start and see what I can scrape out of it. Thought, I was hopping someone have a few simple regular expression for that purpose. Surely, someone must've done it.  Does everyone simply replace line breaks with "<br/>" tags and be done with it? Not so valid conversion.

Comment: @Liming I'm sure there are simpler approaches, but I'am not a .NET man so I don't know what solutions are available. It's not entirely trivial, though, mind you. You would have to deal with a lot of edge cases (spaces, indentations.....) to make this work reliably.

Answer (score -1):

You are not creating paragraphs with `"\r\n"`, you're creating line-breaks. If you want paragraphs, use a [WYSIWYG editor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: Plenty of sites, including this one, turn line breaks into paragraphs intelligently. WYSIWYG editors on the web can be more trouble than they're worth, too - the HTML is often horrendous, among other things. This is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Oh, does it do BLOCKQUOTES too?

Comment: sorry, I didn't make it clear.  Yes, what I'm trying to do is to read a chunk of text submitted through a text area, look at line breaks and convert the user typed "paragraphs" into html "paragraphs" for display purpose. 

Like @ceejayoz mentioend, I don't want to get into WYSIWYG editor as I don't want to process extra unnecessary stuff. Just a few simple cases. 

Thanks